# Routing vs Mapping terminology for Spring REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, terminology

My question is simple. When defining the URL paths for Spring REST API resources, do you call them routes, or mappings? So for example would `https://www.myapp.com/api/person/123` be called a route to a person resource, or a mapping to a person resource?  I have seen both terms used when researching this, and they seem to be somewhat interchangeable but I would like an actual answer. I have tried searching for this but can't seem to find anything on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring docs and the Spring codebase consistently use the term: `mapping`.

For example:

- [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)
- "Annotation for ***mapping*** web requests onto specific handler classes and/or handler methods..." *(my emphasis)*
- "The Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is designed around a DispatcherServlet that dispatches requests to handlers, with configurable handler ***mappings***..." *(my emphasis)*
- ... etc

By contrast, the [Spring MVC docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) make no mention of "routing" or "routes".

However, in general usage the term "routing" is (in my experience, at least) ~common ...

- It adequately describes what's being done i.e. requests are being *routed* by some sort of dispatcher to a specific controller
- Other frameworks (e.g. the Play Framework) use the terms "routing" and "routes"

So, I suspect people will understand your meaning if you use that term however if you want to avoid ambiguity then the more correct form, in the context of a Spring REST API, is "mapping".